# No more Unity after AMD Graphics Driver

Tags: 12.04, unity, drivers, ati, graphics

I seem to have a problem. I am running ubuntu 12.04(64 bit) on my HP ProBooK 4530s (i5-core, 8GB, ATI RADEON HD6790) and I had some heating problems. I've managed to install the graphics driver from the website using this method:

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

All seems well, but when I switch to graphics mode to use the low power Intel onboard graphics card and I restart there are no more Unity elements - the upper menu bar, the dock on the left and when I managed to open a window (right click on the desktop) there are no longer the close, minimize, maximize buttons.

Didn't anyone else encounter this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem when i had gnome installed, but, as first, you can check file:

/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

is it there this line:

greeter-session=unity-greeter

if it is ok try to update and upgrade to try fixing headers in that way.

Comment: Thing is I am able to login, but afterwards I dont have anymore Unity elements. It's just the background with no menu bars, no nothing.